# how to change the visual effects of c++ application?

Tags: c++, winapi, skinning

I've build GUI applications using Win32, MFC and wxWidgets. But the matter is that the style of buttons and other controls looks very bad and poor. So I need to add a theme or a skin to my application; if it is possible?
Thank you.

Comment: What wxWidgets? You tagged your question with WinAPI!

Comment: @J.Doe: I need any sort of skinning wxWidgets or MFC or win32.

Comment: Hmpf. How did you implement your GUI?

Comment: @J.Doe: When creating MFC application or win32 or wxWidgets using Visual C++ 2015. I get bad buttons and controls styles.

Comment: @Maestro Define "bad" exactly. What does your UI actually look like that you don't like? Can you provide a screenshot? Perhaps all you are really [missing is a ComCtrl32 v6 manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/cookbook-overview) to enable [Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/themes-overview), so you are getting the old pre-XP look & feel instead?

Comment: Basically, all controls under the WinApi are windows. You draw them, handle interaction with them and control their output. By doing these three things differently, you more or less get all the different controls offered.

Comment: @enhzflep: How? Would you recommend some tutorial please?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes I mean bad-looking controls of windows.

Comment: @Maestro that still doesn't explain what you consider to be "bad looking" exactly.  WHAT is bad looking to you? Please be more specific.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes I get the WinXp styles.

Comment: @Maestro - please understand, I mean no disrespect when I say this, but it sounds an awful lot like listening to an 18 year old that has just been given the keys to a car, but has never done much more than roll up and down the driveway. This person then approaches a mechanic and asks how to increase the performance of their engine by increasing the compression, changing the cam profile,adding a turbo and cooling the charge-air. They know there's an engine in there and if it's better, the car's quicker - but that's about the extent of their knowledge. How should the mechanic respond?

Comment: @enhzflep: I need only a tutorial on "Skinning".

Comment: @Maestro - Ha! That's what _you_ think. You've no idea just how much more than that you need. Do your own research and you'll discover this. It's unlikely you'd have asked a question (it certainly wouldn't have been *this* one), if you'd done some serious research first.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I am sorry for annoying you. But I get the normal controls' style. But I need something like controls of Winamp or like "Longman dictionnary" these applications don't use the windows controls style. thank you.

Comment: @Maestro "Skinning" requires [subclassing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/subclassing-overview) *every* UI control you create so you can manually draw them. Intercept the [`WM_NCPAINT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/wm-ncpaint) and [`WM_PAINT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/wm-paint) messages directly, handle [`NM_CUSTOMDRAW`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/custom-draw) notifications, etc. It is a LOT of work to skin an application from scratch.  So look for a UI library that supports skinning.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thank you too much. One last thing: Would you recommend some Skinning library.

Comment: @Maestro Asking for recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Ok. Sorry. Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I saw some tutorial of skinning using the API "SetLayeredWindowAttributes()".?

Comment: @Maestro are you asking a question or stating a fact? There are many different APIs that can be used for skinning. Just note that in the case of `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`, you can't use it for skinning child controls prior to Windows 8, as child controls in those versions cannot have the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style applied to them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: okok thank you again. sorry for disturbing you.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that it lacks a common controls manifest? if the absence of it means 'bad' for you:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Comment: See [Enabling Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/cookbook-overview) for more details